# Recent Blog Posts Limit on Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having some problems setting up Number of posts to show on Home Page. When I set the Number of Posts to show in theme options it reverts back to 3. I want to change the number of posts from 3 to 5.

Here is the code block on my home.php which I think needs a bit refinement.

-->

```
            <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=".get_theme_mod('featured_top_left')."&showposts=".get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_num')); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
            <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", true) ): ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><img class="thumb" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/tools/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true); ?>&amp;h=<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_thumb_height'); ?>&amp;w=<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_thumb_width'); ?>&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>    
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This help? http://hypertext.net/2005/02/limit-number-of-posts-with-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wordpress Manual](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters):

> showposts (int) - number of post to show per page. Deprecated as of
>   Version 2.1 in favor of 'posts_per_page'.

So , if you're version is >2.1 you should edit the code and replace `showposts` with `posts_per_page` in the `WP_Query`.

```
        <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=".get_theme_mod('featured_top_left')."&posts_per_page=".get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_num'));
```

**UPDATED CODE.**

Comment: Excellent help Ofir Baruch, absolutely spot on. Worked like a charm.

Comment: What should I do for the theme option then:                                   <p><?php _e("Select which category you want displayed:", 'studiopress'); ?><br />
       <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('selected' => get_theme_mod('featured_top_left'), 'name' => $settings.'[featured_top_left]', 'orderby' => 'Name' , 'hierarchical' => 1, 'hide_empty' => '0' )); ?></p>
    
    <p><?php _e("Number of posts to show:", 'studiopress'); ?><br />
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $settings; ?>[featured_top_left_num]" value="<?php echo get_theme_mod('featured_top_left_num'); ?>" size="5" /></p>

Comment: Ignore it, by rewriting this code you overpassed it.
Just a second , your WP version is >2.1?

Comment: Yes 3.4.2. I'm still unable to change the numbers in theme-options, I'm happy with that also but will be great if I could change that from theme options.

Comment: I have tried that, not working, as soon as I set number of posts to show from 3 to 5 & click update it resets back to 3.

Comment: I'm afraid that there's a bug with the theme , consider ask for the template provider's help (via forum or http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)